# Strip out characters JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm getting a name back but it comes back in this format:

`Gabe Newell (glnewl)`

How do I strip out everthing and just keep the text between the brackets as `var name = glnewl`?

Comment: please post what you have tried

Comment: can you share your code please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var str = "Gabe Newell (glnewl)";
var exp= /\(([^)]+)\)/;
var match= exp.exec(str);

var name = match[1];
```

Demo here: https://jsfiddle.net/rz6m6opy/

Comment: regExp not defined. does it need to be RegExp

Comment: @H30 Try now. It will work. There was a typing mistake since I didn' t test it.
 Also added a demo